# The fan has stopped spinning

Tags: grammar

> The fan is stopped.
>
> The fan has stopped spinning.

Do they sound natural and grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they both sound natural.

Often when the fan is not spinning, one might say

> The fan is **off**.

or

> The fan is **broken**.

if appropriate.

Comment: If a car not able to start. Can I say the car is broken?

Comment: Indeed, yes you can. "I could not go to work today because my car is **broken**."  There does not need to be a visible *break* in the car if the engine is **broken**.

Comment: @Peter I have never heard anyone say that their car is broken. I don't think that is common usage. It is a lot more common to say that your car broke down or that your car has broken down.

Comment: @Phil To me, "**broke down**" is used when you were driving along and then the car "**broke down**", if I go out to my car one morning and it doesn't start, I would say it's either "**broken**" or "**not working**" or simply "**didn't start**".

Comment: @Peter If I heard someone say that their car was broken, I would assume they were a foreigner. It's probably just location differences. I have simply never heard it said. Of course you can say your car isn't working and that's the first thing that would come to mind. On googling I found this: [link](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/244185-My-Car-has-broken-or-is-broken)